# How do I merge back into master without losing my work on github?

Tags: git, github

I have never collaborated before and now find myself needing to share this project with a few others even though I will be doing 90% of the development.

I have a private repo on github. I pushed my initial source with

```
git push origin master
```

then i created a new local branch and made some changes. Then I did some stuff. (It kinda breaks down for me here.) Now, I would like to merge my branch back into master. Locally, it says they're both up to date but on github, it says my 'master' branch has a state of '3 behind'.

Some questions in no certain order?

How do I get my valid branch merged back into master without losing my work?
How should I be doing this in the future?

Comment: Where on GitHub does it say your master branch is '3 behind', and which branch does it say it's behind?  (I've never noticed any status information like that on the GitHub website.)

Comment: @Mark In the “Branch List” tab. http://i.imgur.com/U4aUM.png

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but I'd suggest you make the title a condensed version of the question rather than your humble statement of self-deprecation. ;)  It makes the question easier to find via search.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step 1: Make sure all your changes are checked in.

Step 2:

```
git checkout master
git merge <your local branch>
```

Step 3:

```
git push origin master
```

And, if you want to continue working on your local branch, Step 4:

```
git checkout <your local branch>
```

Comment: Thanks. I would have swore I did that but obviously not. :|